# NgDialog is not working after deploying

Tags: angularjs

I am using NgDialog for showing a popup window which has some operations performed.  It works fine in local . But when deployed it does not . 
But when I remove the controller it works fine everywhere .

I am using ngDialog 1.0.1 , Angular js 1.5 and Typescript 2.1.4

Appreciate your help .

```
showPinVerificationModal(email,name) { 
const dlgConfig = { 
template: require('./modal.tpl.html'), plain: true,
 className: 'ngdialog-theme-modalService ngdialog-theme-modalService-Width800', 
controller: this.PinVerifcationModalCtrl, resolve: {
 email: function () { return email; }, name: function () { return name; }
 } };

 return this.ngDialog.openConfirm(dlgConfig); }



private PinVerifcationModalCtrl($scope,email,name) { $scope.Email = email; $scope.Name = name; }
```

Comment: show some code pls

Comment: @kennasoft added . Thnx

Comment: Have you checked your browser console to see if there was an error? Can you also paste the compiled javascript instead of the Typescript?

Comment: Yes I have checked it . I didn't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways would be
1) Try changing the versions of libraries(ngDialog)
Or 
2) If you are minifying the code in production, check if above is minification safe..